# How to access variables in PyInstaller hook file namespace from runtime code?

Tags: python, git, hook, pyinstaller

I'm trying to get the output of `git describe` evaluated during the PyInstaller analyze phase and made available to a Python runtime variable in order to provide the application a revision string derived from the build environment and displayed at runtime.

To do this I presume PyInstaller hooks are the best means because they allow execution of arbitrary Python code in the hook file while it builds the import tree. However, I have not found a way to communicate a variable value from the PyInstaller analyze phase to a runtime variable so that it can be shown by the application running as the generated `.exe` file.

Example: hook file `hook-rev.py` which is imported by the PyInstaller analyze mechanism when `import rev` is encountered:

```
import git

rev = git.Repo().git.describe()
print('got rev = {}'.format(rev))
```

`mymodule.py` contains:

```
import rev
```

`rev.py` contains:

```
global AppRev
try:
    # Get the revision from the hook file
    AppRev = rev
except:
    print('rev is not defined')
```

Running PyInstaller as:

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. mymodule.py
```

confirms that the hook file import is triggered during PyInstaller analyze phase and the print statement shows the correct result of `git describe` is assigned to the variable `rev` in the scope of the hook file while PyInstaller is building the import tree.  But the generated `.exe` file produces:

```
rev is not defined
```

Of course this is true given the code examples, because `rev` is not in the local or other accessible namespace. I don't know what the namespace of the hook file, and therefore the `rev` variable, is.

By adding this print statement

```
print('module name = {}'.format(__name__))
```

in the hook file `hook-rev.py` I see that PyInstaller's hook import mechanism assigns the name `__PyInstaller_hooks_0_rev` to the imported hook module. But this import exists only during the build, so attempting to access the `rev` variable at runtime in `run.py` as `__PyInstaller_hooks_0_rev.rev` fails since the module `__PyInstaller_hooks_0_rev` is not known at runtime.

Is there another way to bridge the namespaces between the runtime and the PyInstaller hook import processing?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is a way to achieve the required functionality.  It is not an ideal solution because it relies on two additional Python files (hook file, generated file shared between PyInstaller and runtime) to achieve what I'd hope is possible with just the hook file. It also has a downside that the app revision displayed in the dev environment reflects the revision last set by PyInstaller.  I won't mark this as the accepted answer unless it becomes clear that the simpler method is not possible.

The outline is:

1. In the application, use `import rev` which triggers the PyInstaller hook mechanism to look for the file `hook-rev.py` to import during the analyze phase
2. In `hook-rev.py` construct the revision string and write out a Python file e.g. `buildrev.py` that contains an assignment of the revision string to a variable
3. In `rev.py` use `import buildrev` and define `get_rev()` that returns `buildrev.rev`
4. In the application file access the revision string by calling `rev.get_rev()`

The files to implement this scheme are shown below.

`mymodule.py` (the main app):

```
import rev

print('application revision is', rev.get_rev())
```

`rev.py` (defines `get_rev()` which returns the revision string):

```
# import buildrev fails in dev environment if PyInstaller has not been run
try:
    import buildrev
    rev_string = buildrev.rev
except:
    rev_string = 'unknown'

def get_rev():
    return rev_string
```

`hook-rev.py` (the hook file imported by PyInstaller during the analyze phase, generates `buildrev.py`):

```
try:
    # Get the build-time revision string and write it into
    # buildrev.py as a Python variable assignment. Must search
    # parent directories because PyInstaller analyze is run in a lower level.
    rev_string = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True).git.describe()
    with open('buildrev.py', 'w') as rev_file:
        print('rev = \'{}\''.format(rev_string), file=rev_file)
except: 
    pass
```

In the generated file `buildrev.py` the revision string reflects the working copy revision at PyInstaller import tree build time. 
When accessed with normal Python interpreter, as in an IDE in the development environment, that revision string still reflects the version of the workspace at the last run of PyInstaller, which may be inaccurate.
`buildrev.py` should not be tracked by the VCS.